# Buffer overflow: execute char array loaded into memory

Tags: c, linux, assembly, x86, buffer-overflow

I'm an ethical hacking student and have been given this as an exercise. I've been stuck on it for two days now.

We're writing a program that is purposely vulnerable to a "buffer overflow".

```
#include <stdio.h>

void badf(int n, char c, char* buffer)
{

    char mycode[] = {
0xeb, 0x0f, 0xb8, 0x0b,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x8b,
0x1c, 0x24, 0x8d, 0x0c,
0x24, 0x31, 0xd2, 0xcd,
0x80, 0xe8, 0xec, 0xff, 
0xff, 0xff, 0x2f, 0x62,
0x69, 0x6e, 0x2f, 0x6c, 
0x73, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00
}; // 37 bytes

    int i;
    // Copy mycode array into buffer array
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
    buffer[i]=mycode[i];
    }

    // Overwrite Base Pointer
        buffer[37] = 0x00;
    buffer[38] = 0x00;
    buffer[39] = 0x00;
    buffer[40] = 0x00;
    // Overwrite Instruction Pointer
    buffer[41] = 0x90;
    buffer[42] = 0x83;
    buffer[43] = 0x04;
    buffer[44] = 0x08;
}

void f(int n, char c)
{
    char buffer[37];    

    badf(n,c,buffer);
}

void test()
{
    printf("test\n");
}

int main()
{
    f(37,0x00);
    return 0;
}
```

The `mycode` array contains "malicious" machine code (it actually just calls `execv` with `/bin/ls`). `badf` is the "vulnerable" function. At the moment you can see I'm overwriting the Base Pointer with 0x00s and the Instuction Pointer with 0x08048390 which is the address of the `test()` function. This works, 'test' is printed to the terminal.

Now my next exercise is to "use **ddd** to find the address of your code array and modify the C to write this address over the instruction pointer, as you did in the previous step".

What I don't understand, is how I can use **ddd** to find the address of my code array. I can easily find the address where the array is moved to BP:

```
   0x08048260 <badf+12>:        movb   $0xeb,-0x29(%ebp)
   0x08048264 <badf+16>:        movb   $0xf,-0x28(%ebp)
   0x08048268 <badf+20>:        movb   $0xb8,-0x27(%ebp)
.....
```

Or where it is copied into the buffer array:

```
   0x080482f4 <badf+160>:       movl   $0x0,-0x4(%ebp)
   0x080482fb <badf+167>:       jmp    0x8048316 <badf+194>
   0x080482fd <badf+169>:       mov    -0x4(%ebp),%edx
   0x08048300 <badf+172>:       mov    0x10(%ebp),%eax
.....
```

But of course this is not what we're looking for.

**How can I find the Instruction Pointer address to execute machine code that has been loaded in by writing it in the buffer array this way?**

edit: **ddd** is the debugger we're using, also note we're working with a 32bit linux. The code is compiled with `-fno-stack-operator` flag, disabling the compilers auto-checks for buffer overflows.

Comment: break at `badf+12` and dump the adress of `ebp-0x29`

Comment: But this is a base pointer address no? I tried it but my program fails, I don't know if my machine code is wrong..

Comment: I don't think I'm getting the right address, I calculated "bfff f427" by looking where the 0xeb appears in the stack. I think this must be wrong. Is there a command or something in DDD to dump the address of ebp-0x29?

Answer (score 0):

Since you copy `myCode` into the buffer, you could simply use `buffer` itself:

Assuming a little-endian machine:

```
// Overwrite Instruction Pointer
buffer[41] = (char)(((uintptr_t)buffer) >> 0);
buffer[42] = (char)(((uintptr_t)buffer) >> 8);
buffer[43] = (char)(((uintptr_t)buffer) >> 16);
buffer[44] = (char)(((uintptr_t)buffer) >> 24);
```

Comment: I tried exactly that but I get just get a Segmentation Fault. Do I need to take little-endian into account for the malicious code?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do it with ddd, but you could modify `badf` to print `mycode` address by using a print statement like this:

```
printf("mycode address: %p", (void *) mycode);
```

See what that prints, and just write that to instruction pointer

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I tried it however and the mycode address keeps changing every execution

Comment: Then try medinoc's method in the answer below

Comment: I would but I actually need to know how to find this address, not just use the address of the buffer. Is it normal that the address for the code start with 0xbf because it is on the stack? Most of the other instruction pointer addresses we used for the exercise started with 0x08 but 0xbf might be expected in this case?